# how to remove tab bar from a particular screen?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I have created a navigator with 4 tab navigator screens->Home, Search, Upload and Library; and I have stack navigation screens like Sign up, log in, home tabs, and video.
Now, I want to remove the bottom tab bar from the Upload screen but am not sure whether it is possible?

Below is the exact code that I have written:

```
import React from 'react';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {StatusBar} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer, DarkTheme} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {createMaterialBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

import Home from '../screens/Home';
import Search from '../screens/Search';
import Library from '../screens/Library';
import ProfileAuthor from '../screens/ProffileAuthor';
import Shoot from '../screens/Shoot';
import LoginScreen from '../screens/LoginScreen';
import SignUp from '../screens/SignUp';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

function myTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      activeColor="#000"
      inactiveColor="#000"
      barStyle={{
        backgroundColor: '#FFF',
      }}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          title: 'Home',
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons color={color} name="home" size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Search"
        component={Search}
        options={{
          title: 'Search',
          tabBarLabel: 'Search',
          tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons color={color} name="search" size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Upload"
        component={Shoot}
        options={{
          title: 'Upload',
          tabBarLabel: 'Upload',
          tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons color={color} name="add-box" size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Library"
        component={Library}
        options={{
          title: 'Library',
          tabBarLabel: 'Library',
          tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              color={color}
              name="person-outline"
              size={26}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={DarkTheme}>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="login"
          component={LoginScreen}
          options={{
            header: () => null,
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="signup"
          component={SignUp}
          options={{
            header: () => null,
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={myTabs}
          options={{
            header: () => null,
          }}
        />
        
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Video"
          component={ProfileAuthor}
          options={{
            header: () => null,
          }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default Routes;
```

could anyone please tell me whether it is possible in this structure, if yes then how to implement? any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***tabBarVisible**: **false***

It is working when you used **createBottomTabNavigator** from **@react-navigation/bottom-tabs**. but if you will use **createMaterialBottomTabNavigator** from **@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs** to create bottom tabs, it's not working. **createMaterialBottomTabNavigator** can't hide the tab bar, you can see that there is no such option in docs. You should try to nest the bottom-tabs navigator inside the stack navigator if you want it to disappear on the other screens of the stack navigator. The below code is for the hide tab bar in **createBottomTabNavigator**.

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

const BottomTabs = createBottomTabNavigator();

<BottomTabs.Navigator>
  <BottomTabs.Screen name={AppRoute.MORE} component={MoreStack}
        options={({ route }) => ({
            tabBarVisible: getTabBarVisibility(route),
            tabBarLabel: languages.stack_More
        })}
    />
</BottomTabs.Navigator>


const getTabBarVisibility = (route: any) => {
    const routeName = route.state ? route.state.routes[route.state.index].name: '';
   if (routeName === AppRoute.PROFILE
        || routeName === AppRoute.HELP_CENTER
        || routeName === AppRoute.TERMS_CONDITION) {
       return false;
    }
   return true;
}
```